# DRY - Sibling Elements

Tags: javascript, dry

Is there a way to shorten the JS code, need it in vanilla JS not Jquery.

I am unable to use Next and previous sibling concept here.
previousElementSibling and nextElementSibling concept works but what if the selection is more that 3

```js
 document.getElementById("network_tab").addEventListener("click", function(){
  this.classList.add('active');
  document.getElementById("network_tag_tab").classList.remove('active');
  document.getElementById("device_tab").classList.remove('active');
 });
 
 document.getElementById("network_tag_tab").addEventListener("click", function(){
  this.classList.add('active');
  document.getElementById("network_tab").classList.remove('active');
  document.getElementById("device_tab").classList.remove('active');
 });

 document.getElementById("device_tab").addEventListener("click", function(){
  this.classList.add('active');
  document.getElementById("network_tag_tab").classList.remove('active');
  document.getElementById("network_tab").classList.remove('active');
 });
```

```css
.active{
border: 5px solid black;
padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
  <table id="nav-table">
   <tbody>
   <tr>
    <td id="network_tab" class="org_overview_tab active"><a href="#">Networks</a></td>
    <td id="network_tag_tab" class="org_overview_tab"><a href="#">Network tags</a></td>
    <td id="device_tab" class="org_overview_tab left-border"><a href="#">Devices</a></td>
    
   </tr>
   </tbody>
  </table>
```

Comment: Thank you for showing the code, and providing a snippet, but where does your code go wrong? How far did you get writing a generic function to handle this requirement?

Comment: code works, but wanted DRY format of it, if any

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you only need one EventListener ...

```
document.getElementById('nav-table').addEventListener('click', e => {
  if (e.target.nodeName== 'A'){
    document.querySelector('.active').classList.remove('active');
    e.target.parentNode.classList.add('active');
  }
});
```

Comment: How to get the nodeName of column - td

Comment: `console.log(e.target.parentNode.id);`

Answer (score 0):

You can generalize the JS code. That way even if you add more tabs, it will work without changing JS. Check the below code.

```js
var tabs = document.querySelectorAll('.org_overview_tab');
for(var index=0;index<tabs.length;index++) {
  tabs[index].addEventListener('click', function(){
  document.querySelector('.active').classList.remove('active');
  this.classList.add('active');
 });
}
```

```css
.active{
border: 5px solid black;
padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
  <table id="nav-table">
   <tbody>
   <tr>
    <td id="network_tab" class="org_overview_tab active"><a href="#">Networks</a></td>
    <td id="network_tag_tab" class="org_overview_tab"><a href="#">Network tags</a></td>
    <td id="device_tab" class="org_overview_tab left-border"><a href="#">Devices</a></td>
    
   </tr>
   </tbody>
  </table>
```

Comment: this also works, but  need to access based on the id not the class